# shutdown -P works, but shutdown -r does not

Tags: 11.04, server, shutdown, restart

I have a headless Ubuntu Server 11.04 box. If I use:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

It works every time. However, if I instead want to simply restart the machine:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

It fails to do so. Here's a screenshot of what I get when I attempt to shutdown with restart (couldn't figure out which log to get this from). It simply spits this out on the screen and then doesn't progress any further. I have to hold the power button in to turn the machine off after this:

[image]
[(link to full-size image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMIrC.jpg)

Can anyone surmise what might be the problem here? Or perhaps provide some guidance as to how I might diagnose this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to 11.10, this now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should file a bug report on launchpad.net.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your log files, they're located in the directory /var/log/

You can use the `gnome-system-log` tool to do so.